# "Please visit my site" questions

Tags: discussion

I see there are a lot of questions that contain the text "Please visit my site".

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/32733/146
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/30622/146
- [Change Hover color of categories in magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/29189/146)

and the list can go on. 
there are a lot of them posted by [this user](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/9051/user3483987) (but not only)

Some of the questions seam legit, because they let us see an unexpected behavior like javascript or css errors.
But in most of them the website link does not help at all.
I tend to look at these question as being spam-ish and usually vote to close them.
Is this OK? Is a close vote enough or I should flag them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If link to the website has no connection to the actual question, FLAG IT!

Comment: Well...it might have something to do with the question, but it's not at all helpful. See the first link I posted in the question for example: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/32733/146